# NHibernate populates the property however the attribute remains null

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to set the fetchmode to eager for a property that is two levels deep in my object graph.

```
DetachedCriteria homeSupportServicesPlacementInvoiceQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<HomeSupportServicesPlacementInvoice>()
            .SetFetchMode("VendorService", FetchMode.Eager)
            .SetFetchMode("VendorService.Vendor", FetchMode.Eager);
```

NHibernate populates the values of my VendorService object correctly, however after the object is moved to the business layer and is no longer attached to a session, the Vendor property is no longer hydrated.  The only other oddity that I've notices with this process is that in the quickwatch window, while debugging the attribute for VendorService is null while the Property has been set with the proper values.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

For those following the question, apparently you can set the fetchmode for a property that is not in the mapping and it will get populated (and you can see it in the debug) but the values disappear when you detach the object from the session.

Comment: Can you post the code for your property implementation and mapping?

Comment: What does the mapping look like for VendorService. Check that the property Vendor is mapped correctly

Comment: Thanks Tom & Rippo, the problem was with the mapping.  I thought I'd checked them properly, but found the issue while I was cutting code out for my update.

Comment: Can I add my comment as an a answer?

Comment: Sure.  I didn't want to answer the question myself because it was you and tom who actually pointed me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the information you provided I bet that the mapping is incorrect for VendorService.
I would double check that the property Vendor is mapped correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that fields of the proxies are not initialized. The proxy inherits the fields, but doesn't use them. It is only a wrapper which delegates all calls to the real object (also the getters and setters of the property). The real object is another instance, no proxy, which is aggregated by the proxy. The fields of the real object should be initialized properly.

I don't know why you are losing data after serialization. It is most probably a serialization issue and not (very) NH specific.